# Is there a Rails equivalent to PHP's isset()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically just a check to make sure a url param was set. How I'd do it in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && isset($_POST['bar'])){}
```

Is this the rough/best equivalent to isset() in RoR?

```
if(!params['foo'].nil? && !params['bar'].nil?) end
```

Comment: What you have should work if you put ! in front of it. What you're asking in ruby is exactly the inverse of your PHP ( ie it will pass only when `foo` and `bar` are both nil ). So, use `if !params['foo'].nil? && !params ['foo'].nil?`

Comment: Ha yeah, I discovered that just a bit after I went back to my code.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The closer match is probably `#present?`

```
# returns true if not nil and not blank
params['foo'].present?
```

There are also a few other methods

```
# returns true if nil
params['foo'].nil?

# returns true if nil or empty
params['foo'].blank?
```

Comment: params['foo'].present? will evalute to false when params['foo'] is empty string, but isset($_POST['foo']) will evalute to true for the same empty param.

Comment: I said closer, not equal. I also proposed some alternatives.

Comment: Be careful with blank?

It will also come back true if the value is set, but is a boolean false, an empty array, etc.

Comment: How would you test if multi dimentional element is present like `params['type']['type1']['config']`?

Answer (score 25):

You can also use `defined?`

See example from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

```
foo = 42
defined? foo    # => "local-variable"
defined? $_     # => "global-variable"
defined? bar    # => nil (undefined)
```

Many more examples at the linked page.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer. If one tries writing variable.present? or variable.nil? for a variable that is not initialized ruby just blows up. :)

Comment: +100 for Pedro's comment. Php's `isset` is used to check if a variable has even been initialized

Answer (score 13):

Yes. `.nil?` is the equivalent of `isset()` *in that case* when checking the existence of a key in a `Hash`.

You should use `Hash`'s [`key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000765) method, which returns `true` if the given key is present in the receiver:

```
if(params.key?('foo') && params.key?('bar')) end
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I was looking for a test that a variable in a hash was set to `false`. This logic correctly tests that a hash attribute is set and then allows us to utilize the false value.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most important thing, when you migrating from PHP to ROR, is the understanding of the fact that in Ruby everything is true except false and nil

So, your code:

`if(!params['foo'].nil? && !params['bar'].nil?){}`

is equivalent for:

`if(params['foo'] && params['bar']) end`

and this is full equivalent for your PHP code.